# Which parameter should I use to reference an item in a ListView

Tags: android

I just want to know the difference between `int position` and `long id` which are provided in `OnItemLongClickListener` in the `ListView`. I checked both of `int position` and `long id` and they give exactly the same result. Since I need to perform certain action based on the clicked item in a `listView` which one I should use? if there is no difference, then why both of them are available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html)

- position=The position of the view in the adapter.
- id=The row id of the item that was clicked.

Where `position` is the position of view in your listadapter,For e.g. When item clicked then position returns the current position of the view in adapter attached with particular item. 
And `Id` is the id of item in `ListView` For e.g. If item one clicked then it return 0.

So, In your case,
If you want to get adapter item you may use item as `list.getItemAtPosition(position))` 
And if you want only item location in listview then using `id` is right.

Answer (score 0):

Both are different

you need access the item in the listview then choose long id

difference are:

> **position**   The position of the view in the adapter.
>
> **id** The row id of the item that was clicked.

[Refer this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html)

Comment: but there is not any distinguishing feature for both them, they give always the same result.